Probability of Forming an Equilateral Triangle from a Cube's Vertices
From the eight vertices of a cube, if three points are chosen at random to form a triangle, what's the probability that this triangle is an equilateral triangle?
Options:
A. 1/7
B. 1/14
C. 2/7
D. 4/35
combinations = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3}];
vertices = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 
    1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}};
equilateralTriangles = 
  Select[combinations, 
   Module[{v1, v2, v3, d1, d2, d3}, {v1, v2, v3} = vertices[[#]];
     d1 = EuclideanDistance[v1, v2];
     d2 = EuclideanDistance[v2, v3];
     d3 = EuclideanDistance[v1, v3];
     d1 == d2 && d2 == d3] &];
probability = Length[equilateralTriangles]/Length[combinations]
{probability, equilateralTriangles}

Are there any other methods to determine the probability of forming an equilateral triangle by choosing three vertices of a cube?

pts = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
triangles = Subsets[pts, {3}];
test = Equal @@ EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] &;
(Select[triangles, test] // Length)/(triangles // Length)


1/7

Grid[Partition[
  Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], #}] & /@ 
   Triangle /@ Select[triangles, test], UpTo@4], Frame -> All]



Very nice. +1 of course:)

Using Subsets to generate the candidate triangles, and count the ones that have all Pi/3 PolygonAngle:
cubePoints = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3];

candTriangles = Triangle /@ Subsets[cubePoints, {3}];
equilateralCase = ConstantArray[Pi/3, 3];

Count[PolygonAngle /@ 
  candTriangles, equilateralCase]/Length@candTriangles



1/7


  cubePoints, {3}], (PolygonAngle@Triangle@#) == 
   ConstantArray[Pi/3, 3] &]```Also, filter out all the vertex coordinates that form an equilateral triangle.

Overkill but FWIW:
v = MeshCoordinates[MeshRegion[Cuboid[]]];
hf = HoldForm[1/(1 + 2 + 3)] /. 
  CountsBy[
   Union[Extract[DistanceMatrix[#], {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}]] & /@ 
    Subsets[v, {3}], Length]
ReleaseHold[hf]


